# xilinx fpga resource estimation

Tags: fpga, xilinx, estimation

I am trying to understand how to estimate FPGA resource requirement for a design/application.

Lets says Spartan 7 part has,
Logic Cells - 52160
DSP Slices  - 120
Memory      - 2700

How to find out number of CLB's, RAM, and Flash availability?

Lets say my design needs a SPI interface in FPGA,
How to estimate CLB, RAM and Flash requirement for this design?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an electronics question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm torn when it comes to FPGA's because you write code to synthesize into a physical part.  I can make a case that the code that is written represents a certain amount of logic which is what he wants to know, however it does depend on the chip architecture which is electronics.  FPGA's are code and hardware.... super torn.  The question could be better written.

Answer (score 0):

Estimation of a block of logic can be done in a couple ways.  One method is to actually pen out the logic on paper and look at what registers you are planning on creating.  Then you need to look at the part you working with.  In this case the Spartan 7 has CLB config as below:
[image]

This is from the Xilinx UG474 7 Series document, pg 17.  So now you can see the quantity of flops and memory per CLB.  Once you look at the registers in the code and count up the memory in the design, you can figure out the number of CLB's.  You can share memory and flops in a single CLB generally without issue, however, if you have multiple memories, quantization takes over.  Two seperate memories can't occupy the same CLB generally.  Also, there are other quantization effects.  Memories some in perfect binary sizes, and if you build a 33 bit wide memory x 128K locations, you will really absorbes 64x128K bits of memory, where 31 bits x 128K are unused and untouchable for other uses.

The second method of estimating size is more experienced based as is practiced by larger FPGA teams where previous designs are looked at, and engineers will make basic comparisons of logic to identify previous blocks that are similar to what you are designing next.  You might argue that I2C interface isn'a 100% like a SPI interface, but they are similar enough that you could say, 125% of I2C would be a good estiamte of a SPI with some margin for error.  You then just throw that number into a spread sheet along with estimates for the 100 other modules that are in design and you call that the rough estimate.

If the estimate needs a second pass to make it more accurate, then you should throw a little code together and validate that it is functional enough to NOT be optimizing flops, gates and memory away and then use that to sure up the estimate.  This is tougher because optimization (Read as dropping of unused flops) can happen all too easily, so you need to be certain that flops and gates are twiddle-able enough to not let them be interpreted as unused or always 1 or always 0.

To figure out the number of CLB's you can use the CLB slice configuration table above.   Take the number of flops and divide by 16 (For the 7 Series devices) and this will give you the flop based CLB number.  Take the memory bits, and divide each memory by 256 (again for 7 series devices) and you will get the total CLB's based on memory.   At that point just take the larger of the CLB counts and that will be your CLB estimate.